# How to extract text from XML based on a tag & then put it back (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have a messy XML, with some tag structure like -

```
<textTag>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><p> -----some text goes here-----
    </p>
    </div>
</textTag>
```

I want to extract `-----some text goes here-----`, make some changes and put it back into the XML. How should I go about it?

Comment: Try a parser like beautifulsoup to manipulate the text

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

You can use the `xml` module of python for parsing, updating and saving the xml file. A problem though, would be that the resulting xml file might have order of attributes etc different from the original xml file. So when you make a diff, you might see a lot of differences.

So you might do something like.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('xmlfilename')
root = tree.getroot()
p_nodes = root.findall('.//<p>')
for node in p_nodes:
   # process
tree.save()
```

Option 2:

Use regular expression.

Read the file line by line and look for the pattern you are interested in and make the update and write it back. 
The obvious advantage being the diff between the original and modified file will shown only the update you made.

```
import re

with open(outputfile) as fout:
   with open(xmlfile) as f:
      data = f.readlines()
      pattern = re.compile(r"...") # your pattern
      for line in data:
         re.sub(line, pattern, update)
         fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Can't query on <p> (in your first approach). There can be way too many of those. Just need the ones under <textTag> (which can be assumed to be unique).

Comment: I was just suggesting the approach. Obviously you need to choose appropriate `xpath` expression.

Comment: https://devhints.io/xpath is a good xpath cheatsheet, that you can refer to.

Comment: If you're worried about diffing, you should probably create canonical versions of the before/after XML and diff those.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) (which has much better [XPath 1.0 support than ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)) to find all `text()` nodes that contain "-----some text goes here-----", modify the text, and then replace the [.text (or .tail)](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text) of the parent.

Example...

**Python 3.x**

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<textTag>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><p> <br/>-----some text goes here-----
    </p>
    </div>
</textTag>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
for text in tree.xpath(".//text()[contains(.,'-----some text goes here-----')]"):
    parent = text.getparent()
    new_text = text.replace("-----some text goes here-----", "---- BAM! ----")
    if text.is_text:
        parent.text = new_text
    elif text.is_tail:
        parent.tail = new_text

etree.dump(tree)
```

**Output** (dumped to console)

```xml
<textTag>
    <div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><p> ---- BAM! ----
    </p>
    </div>
</textTag>
```